# how to fetch data from another screen and show in the listview items on pressing the button

Tags: java, android

I have a screen which have editText and a button and listview, now when we click on the button it will fetch the Text from another screen and set to the listview items. The problem is when the text has been set to edittext and search for the particular information from other screen.????

Comment: cant understand what are you looking for. plz provide exact imformation.

Comment: What do you mean with "screen"? Activity or what? Please specify!

Comment: Do you want to populate listview item, string from another activity ?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do clearly.